# com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, velocity

I have a query:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.procedures WHERE name ='stProcedure')
DROP PROCEDURE stProcedure
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE stProcedure
AS
CREATE TABLE [core_schema].MyTable(
firstcolumn  int,
secondcolumn int
);
```

And id Java code I have:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(createProcedureQueryString).executeUpdate();
```

How to substitute GO or make it work? In MS SQL Server 2008 it works but when I want to make it work from java code I get an

```
errorcom.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'
```

Comment: How to substitute GO or make it work. In MS SQL Server 2008 it works but when i want to make it work from java code i get an errorcom.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'

Answer (score 6):

GO is not a valid SQL statement.

GO is a "command" for "SQL server management studio" and few other tools to read and to execute. It is not for the SQL Server.

You do not need "GO" in the SQL statement. you need a ";".

Comment: No. GO is a batch separator and GO is definitely needed at this place.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 

GO is not a Transact-SQL statement; it is a command recognized by the sqlcmd and osql utilities and SQL Server Management Studio Code editor

Answer (score 0):

> With Answer "Dennis Cheung" +

Another remark is that one can not execute DDL statement inside Stored Procedure, you will get en error with this given code.